# Ethernet PHY MAC Address - DHCP Request not responding

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ethernet, shift-register, mac

I am working with this [Ethernet PHY](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002260A.pdf) and little bit confused on the topic of MAC address.

This is the - [MAC Controller IC](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/698/REN_r01ds0365ej0110_ra6m4_DST_20200929-2930852.pdf). I'm using RMII interface.

One thing I want to understand is that what should I do on the MAC Address?

I understand that MAC address is a layer 2 topic and the PHY device has nothing to do with it.

So, the MAC Controller has the MAC Address.

My question is, should I set the MAC address from the PHY to the controller? Or does the Controller has a MAC address on its own?

How can I find the MAC address using the registers of the PHY? Is it possible that I can detect some information regarding the MAC Address through the PHY (somehow through the register dump)?

PHY Register dump:

PHY Register 0 = 0x1100
PHY Register 1 = 0x782D

Can someone help me with this MAC address topic.

**EDIT:**

I have checked. Below is my observation : When the Renesas send the DHCP request, I have the feeling (not 100% sure, I will try to find it out) that no response comes from the LAN8700. Do you have a good hint how to find it out (I'm trying to measure it with an oscilloscope, but decoding could be a problem..)? Will add this in the above question under the edit section.

Comment: The MAC address is something you as the user/programmer of the device must provide -It's not built into the PHY.

Comment: But you said it yourself already, a PHY has nothing to do with MAC addresses.

Comment: Why do you say the PHY has nothing to do with the MAC address and then you want to use the PHY to find out the MAC address...?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm confused with the topic on how to see the MAC address, which device has it and who and how can it be set or changed? If MAC address is not visible in the network, what could the fix? Please provide help in simple terms

Comment: I think this question is beyond electronics already. You can simply buy MAC addresses in order to manufacture Ethernet devices with a MAC address.

Comment: So, the MAC address is entirely inside the MAC Controller right? @Justme. It has nothing to do with PHY right?

Comment: In that case, what to do if PHY cannot detect the MAC address in the network? Any idea on what could be the issue?

Comment: PHY does not do MAC address detecting. What you see is normal.

Comment: Oh, in that case, what could be the issue? could there be a possibility that there might be a MAC address, but the PHY is not seeing it? Or there is no MAC address at all?

Comment: " Or there is no MAC address at all?"  Have you set a MAC address in your firmware, and written the MAC address values to the proper registers in the RA6?  Perhaps you should include the setup code in your question.  "what could be the issue?"  Please tell us again the problem is that you are observing, as the current version of your post does not really ask a question about an observed failure.

Comment: PHYs do not "see" MAC addresses. PHYs blindly transmit out what the MAC tells it to, and they blindly receive data on wire to MAC. It is unclear what the actual problem is.

Comment: Oh, now I understand that, MAC Address is something that we set on the MAC Controller registers. Ok, thank you. Let me check.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked @Justme. Below is my observation : When the Renesas send the DHCP request, I have the feeling (not 100% sure, I will try to find it out) that no response comes from the LAN8700. Do you have a good hint how to find it out (I'm trying to measure it with an oscilloscope, but decoding could be a problem..)? Will add this in the above question under the edit section. Please help

Comment: You have now completely changed the direction of the question from subject A to include subject B which invalidates comments and anwers. If you have a new problem, ask a new question. How MAC addresses work have nothing to do with now your board having communication problems, and to figure that out, we need schematics and code which I am sure your company won't give.

Answer (score 7):

You, as the designer, determine your device's MAC address. You have options:

- Buy a support chip that your uC talks to in order to retrieve an unique MAC address that the support chip already has in ROM (for my low-quantity products, this is what I do).
- Get yourself a list of legitimate MAC addresses (requires $money$ Google it). Pick an address from that list, apply it to your device from your firmware.  (Unique address, not to be used again).
- Tell everyone 'Good luck!' and make up your own address (note: If I recall correctly, there is a block of MACs that are designated to be lawlessly used, assuming the device remains only on your isolated subnet).  See next item below.
- Make up a locally unique MAC, and set the "locally Administered Addresses" (LAA) bit in the MAC address. (See Wikipedia "MAC Address" :  "Universal vs. local (U/L bit)".  *" ...setting (assigning the value of 1 to) the second-least-significant bit of the first octet of the address."* I'm not familiar with this method or the ramifications on your LAN.

For the RA6M4 family, it appears that you set the MAC in the **MAHR** & **MALR** registers (RA6M4 Group User’s Manual: Hardware 26.2.15, 26.2.16).

(https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/man/ra6m4-group-user-s-manual-hardware?language=en&r=1333976)

Good luck!

Comment: I had a buddy who did electronics as a hobby and worked at an electronics recycler. He had a side passion of harvesting MAC addresses from equipment that was going to scrap. All the equipment was made irrevocably non-functional during recycling so the MACs truly were “freed”. I don’t know what he did with the list – it was many thousands MACs long. He had a little PIC+ENC battery powered dongle to plug into a port, power the device up, and spit out any source MACs on the little 2-line LCD.

Comment: Personally, if I need some MACs for projects, I go to a thrift store and buy whatever cheap stuff has ethernet ports on it. $2.50 consumer cable modems/routers are great – you get two MACs at least. One for the Ethernet side, another for the cable side.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica why bother, if you can just set up locally administered ones?

Comment: Thank you, I have checked. Below is my observation : When the Renesas send the DHCP request, I have the feeling (not 100% sure, I will try to find it out) that no response comes from the LAN8700. Do you have a good hint how to find it out (I'm trying to measure it with an oscilloscope, but decoding could be a problem..)? Will add this in the above question under the edit section.

Comment: @Newbie Use Wireshark ( https://www.wireshark.org/ )on your dhcp server to monitor transactions on your network segment.  Your LAN 8700 does not care about, nor does anything with, dhcp requests.  It just tickles the transformer, and provides a bit of intelligence to the interface.  DHCP is handled by an external server on your network (that you set up).  You can tell if the 8700 is working with Wireshark.  You can tell if your uC is working with your debugger.  If I were you, I'd start simple, and confirm the system works with a fixed IP on your uC, then try enabling DHCP once it's all good.

Comment: Because you started another question (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/627355/ethernet-phy-mac-controller-dhcp-request-not-responding) Please consider reverting this question back to its original form, and marking it as answered.  Changing the nature of an existing question makes this forum les useful for future people searching for answers.