# Ethernet PHY MAC Controller - DHCP Request not responding

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, high-speed, phy, mac

I am working with this [Ethernet PHY](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002260A.pdf).

This is the - [MAC Controller IC](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/698/REN_r01ds0365ej0110_ra6m4_DST_20200929-2930852.pdf). I'm using the RMII interface.

When Renesas send the DHCP request, I have the feeling (not 100% sure, I will try to find it out) that no response comes from the LAN8700. Anyone has a good hint on how to find it out (I'm trying to measure it with an oscilloscope, but decoding could be a problem..)?

Comment: The PHY does not know what a DHCP request is so what response do you expect from it? You want to determine if you can send and receive packets, DHCP is further up the chain. Maybe the phy has a loopback feature you can use to diagnose your problems?

Comment: @Newbie Use Wireshark ( wireshark.org )on your dhcp server to monitor transactions on your network segment. Your LAN 8700 does not care about, nor does anything with, dhcp requests. It just tickles the transformer, and provides a bit of intelligence to the interface. DHCP is handled by an external server on your network (that you set up). You can tell if the 8700 is working with Wireshark. You can tell if your uC is working with your debugger. If I were you, I'd start simple, and confirm the system works with a fixed IP on your uC, then try enabling DHCP once it's all good.

Comment: so everything works with a static IP?